# visual studio code is forced over two lines

Tags: c#, visual-studio

With my visual studio the code has changed where now long strings are forced over two lines instead of a scroll bar being used to move horizontally. How can I turn this off?

[image]

Comment: [How to manage word wrap in the editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165339.aspx)

Comment: Cheers, didn't know it was called word wrap

Comment: Goto Edit->advanced->WordWrap....
Click on it and you should be able to see your code over horizontal scrollbar